# AngularJS - Update Controller on Route Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

**Setup**

```
 app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.data = $routeParams;
 }]);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
     function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.
             when('/:url', {
                 template: '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
             })
 }]);
```

**Layout**

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="headerController">
      Current Url:{{data.url}}
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="#/pageA">Page A</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#/pageB>Page B</a>
     </li>
</body>
```

**Problem**

I want the header section to constantly update with the current url everytime the route changes. When I load my app for the first time, this works. However, if I change the route, the controller does not update to the new url.

My question is not about solving this exact problem because I know there are other ways to do it, but rather solving it using this setup. In other words, I need to know how to provide a controller outside of a view with my current route, and have that controller update every time the route is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to make $scope.data a function to have it reevaluate.

Otherwise I suggest you listen to onRouteChangeSuccess to watch the URL change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and with some slight changes such as in the following, it is perfectly working on my side with firefox. The url correctly updates to Page A or Page B on change

I also may have not understood the question?

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.data = $routeParams;
 }]);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
     function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.
         when('/:url', {
             template: '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
         })
 }]);



<html ng-app="app">
<head> 
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="headerController">
      Current Url:{{data.url}}
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="#/pageA">Page A</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="#/pageB">Page B</a>
       </li>
</body>
```

Cheers

Nicolas